# Imacros.. file by default appends extension even on mentioning the extension

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am taking a screenshot of an element on a webpage but it saves the image in a .cgi format of .php format(in each case respetively). How to not let file take default extension ?

For eg.

```
VERSION BUILD=8850919 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=about:newtab
URL GOTO=http://falcon.spectranet.com/llmrtg/cgi-bin/llmrtg.cgi
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:llmrtg ATTR=NAME:cp_id CONTENT=*****
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:llmrtg ATTR=NAME:cp_pwd CONTENT=*****
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:llmrtg ATTR=*
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_image WAIT=YES 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://falcon.spectranet.com/llmrtg/cgi-bin/graph.cgi?
cp_id=17197&session=* CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEPICTUREAS
```

In this example I get `image.cgi` and if I mention `FILE=+_image.jpg` then my file is renamed as `image.jpg.cgi` , how can i get rid of `.cgi`Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEPICTUREAS` I changed it to `CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT` in the last line. This worked for me , my file is now saved as `.png`

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://falcon.spectranet.com/llmrtg/cgi-bin/graph.cgi?cp_id=17197&session=* CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT
```

Rest everything is same.

Answer (score 0):

```
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_image.png WAIT=YES
```

Does this help?